# Does Paw include compression functionality? ie: a zlib extension

Tags: paw-app

I am looking to take a JSON file, convert it to a Base64 string, and use Zlib to compress it.  I can't find any compression options or extensions for this in Paw.  Am I missing it?

Comment: It's true it's not yet available but it should be really simple for us to add this! Will try to do it asap.